# Tabula missing last columns - any idea?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, tabula

any help would be appreciated;

I'm reading the PDF, exporting to csv and loading using Pandas. I could not read the correct way using pdf instead.

However, it is missing the last column

"**Quantidade**"

##### Create csv file

```
tabula.convert_into("https://up2dataweb.blob.core.windows.net/bdi/BDI_03-2_20231124.pdf", "outputopcoes.csv", \
                    output_format="csv", pages=291)
```

##### reading csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('outputopcoes.csv')

df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 10']).rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).iloc[2:]

df
```

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Yes, I could import it, however, the last column is still missing.
I do not know why, but the last column "Quantidade" is missing. Maybe, some failure related to the tabula itself.(no idea)

Comment: would you be able to provide an example how did you extract it ? I tried with PyPDF2 generating the txt file which is very hard to understand. Likwise, I tried to load it using rea_csv from panas, but, I got only one columns. Thanks again

Comment: like a charm ! Thank you very much @kj